# How can I make the changes of Gaia apply to device

Tags: firefox-os

I edit the system app(homescreen) in the gaia folder,
and flash the device,
but it doesn't work, not thing change at all.
I've already try it on the simulator,
it runs as well.
Could somebody tell me how to make the changes apply to the real device ?
thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of answering on this post. StackOverflow is Q&A, not a forum. Put the log file somewhere in a gist and add a link to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is two ways you can do it. If all you want is change the homescreen, you can now create a homescreen app and set it as the homescreen in Settings (push via the app manager like any app). There is a nice example [here](https://github.com/michalbe/firefoxos-tilescreen).

If you want to flash the gaia homescreen to your phone, there is a couple of things you need to do:

1. Update the phone to the correct version (nightly if you're editing master, 1.4 if you're editing upstream/v1.4 branch). This is because gaia & gecko version are tightly coupled.
2. Enable Remote debugging in Settings
3. Verify that you can talk to the phone via the app manager
4. In the terminal, run `adb root` and `adb remount` to make sure you have to right permissions (this is probably where it goes wrong)
5. In the gaia directory run: `make reset-gaia`

This should flash all of gaia now. If you continue editing you can make incremental changes to homescreen and push them via:

```
APP=homescreen make install-gaia && adb shell stop b2g && adb shell start b2g
```

If this doesn't work, please write the output of `make reset-gaia` to a log file and add it as a comment to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jan,

I'd tried it, but it doesn't work.

I'd tried both ways.

1、I download the package and use app manager to install it into the device(Nexus-S), it can be done, but nothing change, and I tried to install the package into the simulator, it can be done, then I edit the css, it apply the changes right away, it's very strange.

Comment: 2、The firefox OS version on my device(Nexus-S) is "2.1.0.0-prerelease". I type the the following command "adb root", and the terminal shows that "adbd is already running as root", and I type "adb remount", finally I type make reset-gaia, but it doesn't work, after reboot, I type "APP=homescreen make install-gaia && adb shell stop b2g && adb shell start b2g", It still doesn't apply the changes to the device. so I use the command "make reset-gaia" and output to a log file. please check the following information :

Comment: adb shell stop b2g
adb shell rm -r /cache/*
rm failed for /cache/lost+found, Directory not emptyadb shell rm -r /data/b2g/*
adb shell rm -r /data/local/webapps
rm failed for /data/local/webapps, No such file or directoryadb remount
remount succeeded
adb shell rm -r /system/b2g/webapps
adb shell 'if test -d /persist/svoperapps; then rm -r /persist/svoperapps; fi'
run-js-command gaia/preferences
run-js-command gaia/pre-app
[svoperapps.js] PROFILE_DIR, GAIA_DISTRIBUTION_DIR, VARIANT_PATH are all required
execute Makefile for calendar app

Comment: make[1]: Entering directory `/home/leslie/Nexus-S/gaia/apps/calendar'
cp -r "/home/leslie/Nexus-S/gaia/apps/calendar" "/home/leslie/Nexus-S/gaia/build_stage"